# Visual Studio Formatting New Lines C# Methods

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I don't want to place the open brace on new line for methods.
So I have the following checkbox unchecked:

Tools>Options>C#>Formatting>New Lines>Place open brace on new line for methods

```
protected void MyMethod() 
{
}
```

I want this when I hit the } key

```
protected void MyMethod() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option you need to set in **Tools/Options** to activate the formatting when you enter the } character.

Uncheck the *Leave Block on Single Line* option in the **C#/Formatting/Wrapping** section.

[image: The Leave Block on Single Line option]
[image]